# How to disable audio jack programatically in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, headset

Is there a way to disable Android `Headset` even if it is connected to mobile. I have been using `Media Button` in my headset to fire some events. I don't want the event to be performed all the time. So i want the Headset jack disabled after i send a message from a number which is `Hardcoded`. I have used SMS `BroadcastReceiver` to disable or enable Mobile data and restarting the application. I don't know is there a way to disable the audio jack of mobile. If there is any method please let me know.

Comment: Just ignore the Media Button clicks whenever you don't want your event triggered. There's no need to disable the audio jack.

Comment: I've unregistered the event receiver for `Media Button` using this `unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver`. Anyway thanks.